# SQL issue with CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to adjust the following statement:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN UPPER(JobTitle)
                    ELSE JobTitle END as 'Job Title', COUNT(BusinessEntityID) as 'number of employees'
    FROM HumanResources.Employee
    WHERE OrganizationLevel < 3 
    GROUP BY JobTitle, OrganizationLevel
    ORDER BY JobTitle ASC
```

I need to change it so as to make JobTitle appear as 'SOMETHING ELSE' when the OrganisationLevel is 1.

I thought this would be a simple matter of making a small change to the CASE statement so JobTitle would be = 'SOMETHING ELSE' but it won't allow me to do this,

Comment: You get an error about group by? You should have the same statement in group by as you have in select

Comment: group by doesn't give me an error, as is the statement works but i need it to show JobTitle as 'something else' when the organisationlevel = 1

Comment: Oh then maybe the problem is that you have < 2 first so it uses that instead of = 1?

Comment: Please post the query that didn't work, and what error you received if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have same `case` statement in `Group by`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN OrganizationLevel = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING_ELSE'
         WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN Upper(JobTitle)
         ELSE JobTitle
       END                     AS 'Job Title',
       Count(BusinessEntityID) AS 'number of employees'
FROM   HumanResources.Employee
WHERE  OrganizationLevel < 3
GROUP  BY JobTitle,
          CASE
            WHEN OrganizationLevel = 1 THEN 'SOMETHING_ELSE'
            WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN Upper(JobTitle)
            ELSE JobTitle
          END
ORDER  BY JobTitle ASC
```

Comment: close but It brings up an error : Column 'HumanResources.Employee.OrganizationLevel' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN OrganizationLevel < 2 THEN UPPER(JobTitle)
                    ELSE WHEN  OrganizationLevel =1 THEN 'SOMETHING ELSE' ELSE JobTitle END as 'Job Title', COUNT(BusinessEntityID) as 'number of employees'
    FROM HumanResources.Employee
    WHERE OrganizationLevel < 3 
    GROUP BY JobTitle, OrganizationLevel
    ORDER BY JobTitle ASC
```

Comment: 'Something Else' will never be returned, because 1 < 2.

Comment: I could remove < 2 as it won't be necessary if I'm right but that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Correct. But it was just to illustrate how to fit an extra condition in CASE.